# Android : how to make View Flow with bottom shadow like iphone

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, viewflow

Going straight forward..

1.what i achieved so far (thanks to pakerfeldt- https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)
[image: Android]

2.what i need actually

[image: IPhone]

so almost done..but you can see bottom shadow functionality (at viewflow) in iphone screen (and it can pull down and can see entire image). so does anyone achieved something similar in android ?
any other library for reference ?

Thanks in advance. answer will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah..i have done some thing similar see..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.potterish

Comment: good would you like to help me how to do image switch automatically. I have also done it with viewpager but i need to swap images automatically. Please share a bit code.